# How to model an attribute with ordered states?

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

Dealing with attributes with an ordered state is something that I've dealt with many times. For example, an issue in an issue tracker can have an `open`, `pending`, or `closed` state. To make sorting and querying easier, it is tempting to store the state as an integer. However, this makes it less trivial to add new states? For example, a new state, `delayed`, that falls between `pending` and `closed` will introduce problems when the state is stored as an integer.

**Is there a pattern or concept to use a sortable type, such as an integer, for storing the state of an issue without compromising extensibility?**

One approach that comes to mind is avoiding subsequent values. Instead of assigning `0` to `open` and `1` to `pending`, it may be better to assign `10` to `open` and `20` to `pending` to leave room for extensibility. Is this a common pattern?

Comment: Don't use a single integer to represent both state and order.

Comment: Mike, he is clearly referring to the ordering of states in some workflow/process(/petri net ?).  How can you use any non-ordered type to represent this ordering ?  Is your suggestion to model the possible orderings of the possible states explicitly elsewhere (binary relation "state X precedes state Y") ?  i.e. explicitly define the relevant ordering operator for the type as a table in the database ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout: I'm recommending simply that the sort order have its own column.

Answer (score 0):

I think using integers with a certain offset (like 10, 20, ...) is just a hack, but no general conceptual solution to your problem.

A general solution is to use a class (like `State`) having two positive-integer-valued attributes (like `enumNo` and `seqNo`), one for providing an identifier for the (`State`) enumeration literal, and one for defining the linear order.

Answer (score -1):

It was already applied by BASIC in the seventies.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Are you referring to the approach I mention in the question?

Comment: BASIC had numbered lines, and by default they were numbered 10,20,30,... so it was relatively easy to insert lines in between existing ones.  It also had a RENUMBER command (which is also a necessary feature in many cases, which is what most other applications of the pattern do not implement, but which may also be inconvenient to implement in many use cases).  Does that look like anything in your question ?

Comment: BASIC or COBOL line numbering  has nothing to do with data modeling and database design

Comment: Lines of BASIC source code are just as much "data" as anything else.  Even if only to the compiler/interpreter.  And therefore they can equally well be subjected to an exercise of "modeling" as anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
Ordering patterns do not exit in relational models because it violates the first normal form and relation definition. Non relational database models use List or Array data structure to define  ordering.

Comment: You weren't asked for your opinion on what should be the right way to model the problem.  The question was about the pattern of interleaved numbering of things that are considered data to some processing engine.

Comment: @Erwin Smout It is not a my opinion, ordering patterns do not exit in relational model by definition see Wikipedia     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: "Non relational database models use List or Array data structure to define ordering."  And the relational database model allows to model ordering of things by including an attribute called, e.g. "ORDINAL" or "ORDER" and setting values for it to 1,2,3,... or 10,20,30,... in the tuples and relations that make up your database.

Comment: @Erwin it is possible to implement persistent ordering in relational databases in many ways but it is application level model e.g. ORM implementations support mappings to List, Enum but it is not data modeling or database design scope.  Simple way to implement ordering is "weight" attribute, it might be important for some particular application but it should be better to calculate value weight for sorting in application.